# Get the Text widget that is focused [tkinter]

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Simple question, not sure if there is an answer.
Imagine you have 2 text boxes in a tkinter window, is it possible to know which of the 2 the user is focused on, then return the text widget object itself, or a variable that tells you something.
**Context: **Trying to insert a set of characters at the users cursor, but I want it to add it at their cursor regardless of the text box. Instead of:
`self.text1.insert(tk.INSERT, " Some text...")`, I want `self.focusedText.insert(tk.INSERT, " Some text at your cursor in the focused text widget...")`. *Is there some way to figure out which of many Text widgets a user is focused on?* Thanks!

Comment: Can't find anything answering my question.

Comment: search for the method `focus_get`